# Separating Rows in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to add blank rows to a WPF DataGrid. To achieve this, I am using GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate to add the blank rows. The catch is that I only want to add the headers if the value of `Grouping` is not an empty string. `Grouping` is a property coming from an object I am using to populate the DataGrid. For example, if `Grouping` is `""`, then I do not want to display a header. If `Grouping` is `"1"`, then I want to display a header.

In this image, "Saw #1 cutting length" and "Saw #2 cutting length" do not need a heading above them as they are not apart of a group. I would like to remove that heading above them. However, the parameters under them are apart of a group, and thus I would like to keep that heading there.

[image: parameters in datagrid]

The concept seems simple enough, but I cannot access the property `Grouping` as I assume I don't have the correct context to get to it. This code is what I have come up with so far:

```cs
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
   <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" >
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock x:Name="Group" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
               </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
         </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
   </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

The method where I am setting the `GroupDescriptions`:

```cs
private void ParametersGroup_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var _sourceList = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = ParameterNames };
   _sourceList.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(ParameterNameListModel.Grouping)));
   ICollectionView ItemList = _sourceList.View;
   ParameterNameList.ItemsSource = ItemList;
}
```